# Datatable: How to dynamically change color for the displayed data

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm generating a datatable and some values are negative. How can I mark them in red?

When defining my table I defined `Total Balance` column as following:

```
{"sType": "string", "sClass": "total"}
```

This is my code to render data:

```
this.DataTableBind = function () {
    var myself = this;
    var aData = new Array();
    for (var ctr = 0; ctr < myself.get_DataSource().length; ctr++) {
        var item = myself.get_DataSource()[ctr];

        if (item.TotalBalance < 0) {
            $('.total').css('color', 'red');
        }

        aData[ctr] = new Array(
                            item.Col1,
                            item.Col2,
                            item.Col3,
                            item.Col4,
                            item.Col5,
                            item.TotalBalance
                        );
    }
```

I need to show `Total Balance` data in red when it is negative

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataTable, but `$('total')` is looking for elements of type `total`. You'd probably need to find elements with class `total`, using `$('.total').css(...)`

Comment: You are right. I forgot the `.` symbol. :) However, it changes color for the Column name. I need to change the color for the data itself

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
    aData[ctr] = new Array(
                        item.Col1,
                        item.Col2,
                        item.Col3,
                        item.Col4,
                        item.Col5,
                        item.TotalBalance.formatMoney(2, '.', ',', '$')
                    );
```